# How to know when the socket has received a FIN packet when using WSARecv() and IOCP?

Tags: c++, sockets, iocp

When using blocking sockets and the `recv()` function, when the socket has received a FIN packet, `recv()` will return `0`.

However, how to know when the socket has received a FIN packet when using `WSARecv()` and IOCP? I think that the `lpNumberOfBytesRecvd` will also be set to `0`, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `WSARecv()` call is in progress when the `FIN` arrives then you will get a successful completion with `lpNumberOfBytesRecvd` set to 0.

If the `WSARecv()` call is initiated after the `FIN` arrives then you may get a `WSAESHUTDOWN` error from the `WSARecv()` call.

I tend to issue a `shutdown(s, SD_RECEIVE)` on the socket when I get the first 'client close' (i.e. zero byte read return) as this then gives the predictable behaviour above and avoids a trip through the IOCP for subsequent attempts to receive...

Comment: What will be the error code when `WSARecv()` returns an error (i.e. what will `WSAGetLastError()` return)?

Comment: In the case where a completion is issued, if the peer disconnects gracefully (sends `FIN`) then I/O success of 0 bytes is reported.  But if the connection is lost abnormally then I/O failure with an error code is reported, such as `ERROR_NETNAME_DELETED` (64). Make sure you are accounting for socket failures and abnormal disconnects.  Not all clients disconnect gracefully, or network mishaps might sometimes lose the `FIN`.

Comment: Yes, but that wasn't what the question was about. :) There are lots of ways for a completion to fail... This isn't actually the failure path, it's the success path with a 0 byte read.

Comment: I have called `WSARecv()` after a FIN packet has been arrived, and `WSARecv()` has returned `0`, and `WSAGetLastError()` has also returned `0`!

Comment: Er, if `WSARecv()` returns success (0) then a completion will be queued, deal with it there. My code to handle `WSAESHUTDOWN` explicitly for `WSARecv()`s as a 'client close' may come from the fact that I explicitly call shutdown(recv) when I get a client close from any `WSARecv()` this guarantees easy to understand behaviour from subsequent `WSARecv()` calls that are issued after this point and avoids the context switch to the IOCP thread to deal with it...

Comment: @RemyLebeau The FIN is subject to acknowledgement and retransmission just like a TCP data segment.

Comment: @LenHolgate: you can optionally use `SetFileCompletionNotificationModes()` to request `FILE_SKIP_COMPLETION_PORT_ON_SUCCESS` if you want to deal with success at the call site rather than in the IOCP queue.

Comment: @EJP: I am aware of that, but that is still no guarantee that it can never be lost.

Comment: If it's lost then it fails to comply with the questioner's criteria ("how to know when the socket has received a FIN packet") as it wasn't received. It simply becomes an error condition...